# How to combine the attributes based on the two columns

Tags: dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe imported from the web as below.

Unfortunately, the values for the size of the bag are in different rows.

| Name | Bag | Length | Width | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | A | 15.32 |  |  |
| James | A |  | 27.33 |  |
| James | B |  |  | 20.69 |
| James | B |  | 15.87 |  |
| Ausines | A | 17.88 |  |  |
| Ausines | A |  | 18.94 |  |
| Ausines | A |  |  | 14.56 |
| Ausines | B |  | 16.82 |  |

I would like to express the size attributes in a single line based on the 'name' and the 'bag' column as follows :

| Name | Bag | Length | Width | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | A | 15.32 | 27.33 |  |
| James | B |  | 15.87 | 20.69 |
| Ausines | A | 17.88 | 18.94 | 14.56 |
| Ausines | B |  | 16.82 |  |

How can I solve this problem? I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Blank cells are empty string or NaN values?

Comment: NaN Value in Blank Cells

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby_first`:

```
out = df.groupby(['Name', 'Bag'], sort=False, as_index=False).first()
print(out)

# Output
      Name Bag  Length  Width  Height
0    James   A   15.32  27.33     NaN
1    James   B     NaN  15.87   20.69
2  Ausines   A   17.88  18.94   14.56
3  Ausines   B     NaN  16.82     NaN
```